# How to add additional features to a table using Angular 6

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel

I have a table made with Angular 6. I want to add a few additional features to the table:

- Overall table search
- Sort by columns
- Page x of n option

How do I add these using Angular 6? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/categories/tables

Comment: Thanks for the link @Vikas. But, this is for AngularJS (Angular 1.x). I am talking about Angular (2.x and above).

Comment: Perhaps you are mistaken the link I have provided is for Angular Material V6 it is not for AngularJS it's for Angular. Observe carefully.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the existing libraries that are available currently, below are few of them:

- [Dev Extreme](https://js.devexpress.com/)
- [JqxWidgets](https://www.jqwidgets.com/)
- [angular-material-data-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-material-data-table#demo)